# Wordpress - front end: get input from custom fields --> how to display front end?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

noob needs help!

I am creating a wordpress site, where I have created a child theme. In this I have a form, that users can fill front end and submit. In this form I have created a few custom fields.

These fields show up front end, takes user input and saves as I want them to.

I need guidance on how to display this new input on another page (preferably using built in WP functions and PHP). I have been looking at the WP function "get_the_content()", but I can't figure out how to use it :-(

These are the functions I have used for creating, populating and saving from custom fields:

```
function return_grades( $grades ) {

$grades = array(
    0 => '-',
    1 => '12',
    2 => '10',
    3 => '7',
    4 => '4',
    5 => '2',
    6 => '0',
    7 => '-03',
);
    return $grades;
}

add_filter( 'submit_job_form_fields', 'custom_submit_job_form_fields' );

function custom_submit_job_form_fields( $fields ) {

$fields[ 'job' ][ 'job_grade' ] = array(
    'label'       => __( 'Evt. karakter modtaget', 'jobify' ),
    'type'        => 'select',
    'options'     => return_grades(),       
    'required'    => false,
    'priority'    => 5
);  

return $fields;
}

add_action( 'job_manager_update_job_data', 'grade_save', 10, 2 );

function grade_save( $job_id, $values ) {
    update_post_meta( $job_id, '_job_grade', $values['job']['job_grade'] );
}
```

In the wordpress theme, there are already functions displaying other information aquired from the user form. This is displayed using:

```
            <div class="job-overview col-md-<?php echo $col_overview; ?> col-sm-12">
            <h2 class="job-overview-title"><?php _e( 'Overview', 'jobify' ); ?></h2>
            <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_job_description', get_the_content() ); ?>
            </div>
```

I need to do something similar to displaying the job title (as the theme does fine already) and instead displaying the grade, which the user has just input. I have already tried the themes support to no avail :-(

I am sure this is a breeze for you guys in here, but I thank you all a LOT in advance for any help! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the update_post_meta function to save the grades to _job_grade.
So to get them back use the get_post_meta function:

```
// http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta
update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value);

// https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta
$meta_values = get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $single );
```

For your code try this:

```
get_post_meta( $job_id, '_job_grade', true); // true since returning single key value
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was aaalmost, what I needed.

This worked:

    <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_job_grade', true ); ?>

...but you got me in the right direction :-)

Comment: Haaha yeah sorry thats to get it but you need to echo it to display it or store in a variable. Need any moe help let me know =)